# Video Frame Pixel Modification

Tags: c#, video

I'd like to apply various modifications to every frame in a video, for instance make every pixel in the first 100 pixels wide black for the length of the frame.

It's actually just for a bit of fun i.e. spoofing some newsreaders back ground pictures with company staff "stories".

Ive looked into FFMPeg just briefly but I'm wondering if there is anything more straight forward considering the nature of the project (I dont want to burn too much time on it).

I literally just want to overwrite patches of screen for x number of frames.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this. http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/

there should be a sample where they draw a spider on the video